# Using FabricJS loadSVGFromURL within a subclass

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs, subclassing

I have a custom subclass in `FabricJS` that is based on a `FabricJS` group:

```
var canvasObject = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {

                  type: 'canvasObject',

                  initialize: function(options) {
                    options || (options = { });
                    this.callSuper('initialize', options);

                    var rectBase = new fabric.Rect({
                       fill : 'red',
                       originX: 'left',
                       originY: 'top',
                       left: options.margin.l,
                       top: options.margin.t,
                       width : (options.width-options.margin.l-options.margin.r),
                       height :(options.height-options.margin.t-options.margin.b),
                    });


                    var labeledRect = new LabeledRect({
                      width: options.width,
                      height: options.height,
                      'idname': options.idname,
                      background: 'transparent',
                      labelFont: '14px Helvetica',
                    });



                    this.callSuper('initialize', [labeledRect, rectBase], options);

                  },

                  toObject: function() {
                    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                      idname: this.get('idname')
                    });
                  },

                  _render: function(ctx) {
                    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
                  }
                });
```

How do I include an SVG within this custom group. I'd like to be able to load an SVG from a URL similar to this:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('example.svg', function(objects, options) {

                    var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                    canvas.add(shape.scale(1));
                    canvas.renderAll();


                  });
```

But have it add to the canvas within my custom group - so that each canvasObject added can have an SVG attached.

I've tried adding the SVG to a PathGroup object - but I'm not sure the asynchronous load is working with it.

I'd also like to be able to update the SVG images within each group. How can I update an SVG path content similar to updating an objects properties?